# Spring hateoas - how to retrieve Complex object

Tags: spring-data, spring-rest, spring-hateoas

I am working on a project which i need to expose complex/nested objects via a rest API. Here i got a question regarding how to assemble the full object as hateoas provides links for related objects. As an example in my project i need to manage Jobs, sub jobs belong to a particular job and customer who owns a particular job. So i used Spring hateoas and developed an API and following is the result for simple API call to get a Job

```
"jobCode": "GM",
"jobDescription": "General Maintenance",
"_links": {
"self": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/jobs/1"
},
"job": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/jobs/1"
},
"taskList": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/jobs/1/taskList"
},
"customer": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/jobs/1/customer"
}
```

Then i need to display the full job information including sub jobs and and its customer using this on the screen. In this case what would be the standard practice?
We can do the API calls one by one till we retrieve all the related objects. But it would be multiple API calls and there can be a performance delay. Is there standard practice there in the Software industry?

Appreciate your feed back

Thanks,

Comment: If you retrieve data from database you should use [Spring Data REST](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) which expose data to json right from database. See getting started [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)...

Comment: Tnaks @Cepr0, yes i tried Spring data rest. Still it does not result the full object. it reurns the most outer object with links to nested objects

Comment: To get 'full' object you can use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts) or [skip exporting repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.hiding-repositories) for nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

you will find what you need in Spring Projection
 https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

check my answer also in this question

[How to loop and retrieve value from HATEOAS _link attribute (e.g. retrieve a description)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554979/how-to-loop-and-retrieve-value-from-hateoas-link-attribute-e-g-retrieve-a-des)